# Entropy generation at the molecular level in a irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility, adiabatic

When we expand an gas irreversibly in an adiabatic process then there is intermolecular friction, but what exactly gets transferred to heat. I have read that the directed motion gets randomized. But which directed motion. Do they mean the translational kinetic energy of a molecule?

Answer (score 2):

In an adiabatic process heat transfer is not involved. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Molecular friction increases the temperature of the system due to an increase in molecular kinetic energy. It is energy transfer by work not heat. It’s like raising the temperature of the skin of your hands by rigorously rubbing them together. It’s friction work not heat transfer that increases the internal energy and temperature of your skin.

Hope this helps